# How should I store and compress a Moose object using Perl?

Tags: perl, compression, store, moose

I have created a package using Moose and I would like to `nstore` some large instances. The resulting binary files are very large (500+MB) so I would like to compress them.

What is the best way for doing that?
Should I open a filehandle with `bzip` etc. then store using `fd_nstore`?

Comment: I finally used `nstore_fd` with a file descriptor opened with a gzip IO layer.

Answer (score 5):

With [MooseX::Storage](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aStorage), most of this is already done for you -- you just need to specify your serialization and I/O formats.

Comment: The doc is really minimal. How can I combine it with e.g. gzip?

Comment: @David: I've only used MX:S myself in very superficial cases, but if you hop on perl.irc.org #moose there is almost always someone around who can help you out.

Answer (score 4):

While compression is certainly a viable option, you might also want consider simply serializing less.

Could it be that your objects contain a lot of data that could easily be rebuilt from other data they also contain? For example, if you have attributes that are lazily build from other attributes (e.g. using Moose's `lazy` + `builder` or `lazy_build`), there is not much point in storing the values of those attributes at all unless the recomputation is incredibly expensive. And even then it might be worth considering, as reading lots of data off disk isn't the fastest thing either.

If you find that you want to serialize only parts of your objects, and still want to use Storable, you can define custom `STORABLE_freeze` and `STORABLE_thaw` hooks, as described in the Storable documentation.

However, there's also alternative serializers available. MooseX::Storage is one of them, and happens to support many serialization backends and formats, and can also be told easily about which attributes to serialize and which to skip for that purpose.

Comment: This is related to `FastRanges` described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790166 (see last update in the original post). The size is inherent to get the needed performance. It still much faster to load then to recreate the object.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Data::Serializer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aSerializer). It optionally uses [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) (via [Compress::Zlib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Compress%3a%3aZlib)) or [PPMd](http://compression.ru/ds/) (via [Compress::PPMd)](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Compress%3a%3aPPMd) to compress your serialized data.